# Adding $...$ in-line math mode in MathJax

Tags: html, configuration, mathjax

I want to use $...$ for in-line math mode with MathJax. In the documentation of MathJax I found the following:

> "if you want to use single dollar signs for in-line math mode, you must enable that explicitly in your configuration:

```
 window.MathJax = {
  tex: {
    inlineMath: [['$', '$'], ['\\(', '\\)']]
  }
};"
```

So, here is my problem. I have no idea of what my configuration is. For example, I have an HTML document and this has parts, for example `<head></head>`, but where in my HTML document do I have to put the code for it to work?

Where do I have to put the code for the notation $...$ to be available in my HTML document?

Comment: You are from *[LaTex in websites](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/618769/latex-in-websites/618787#618787)*, aren't you? - first read the answer very well. Where did you encounter the part? A URL?: > if you want to use single dollar signs for in-line math mode, you must
> enable that explicitly in your configuration: What guide are you following? *[MathJax Documentation](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/index.html)*?